# Create & use a WPF page with C++/CLR

Tags: wpf, xaml, c++-cli, clr

I want to use C++/CLR to create a UI for my app. I need C++/CLR because I deal with a lot of native win32 C++ code. So I tried to make my app with the following steps, but they don't work:

Make an empty project

Unicode charset and enable /clr

Add refrences to PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System, and WindowsBase

Add the App.xaml, App.xaml.h, MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.xaml.h

Add the InitalizeComponent code to MainWindow.xaml.h (that
s where i'm having trouble.)

This is my mainwindow.xaml.h code

```
#pragma once
using namespace System::Windows;
using namespace System;
namespace Project2
{
    public ref class MainWindow : Window
    {
    public:
        MainWindow()
        {
            System::Uri ^resourceLocater = gcnew System::Uri("component\MainWindow.xaml", System::UriKind::Relative);

#line 1 "..\..\MainWindow.xaml"
            System::Windows::Application::LoadComponent(this, resourceLocater);
        }
    };
}
```

My entry point code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "App.xaml.h"
#include "MainWindow.xaml.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows;
[STAThreadAttribute]

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE a, HINSTANCE b, LPSTR c, int d)
{
    auto win = gcnew Project2::MainWindow();
    auto app = gcnew Project2::App();
    app->Run(win);
    return 0;
}
```

And here's my app.xaml.h code:

```
#pragma once
using namespace System::Windows;
namespace Project2
{
    public ref class App : Application
    {
    public:

    };
}
```

The MainWindow.xaml and App.xaml all contain valid markup.
I tried chaning the values for the System::Uri resoucelocator but nothings chaning. I just get `System.IO.IOException: The mainwindow.xaml was not found`

Any ideas?

Comment: Mission impossible. Use C#+WPF for GUI. Use DllImport to native C++ library. Or use C++/CLI to writing managed wrappers.

Comment: @Alexander_Petrov Make this comment an answer.

Comment: Aw man. Ok, ill do that. I was hoping this would work...